# Refetch Query on Navigating to screen again React Native

Tags: react-native, graphql

I have a requirement in React Native to refetch the Query when navigating again to a screen. My code is:

```
const { refetch } = useQuery(all_DriverNotifications, {
        variables: {
            driverId: user.driverId,
        },
        fetchPolicy: "network-only",
        // skip: (user.driverId == ''),
        onError: (error) => {console.log("error in all subs and trans",error)},
        onCompleted: (data) => {
          console.log('here');
            if (data && data.allDriverNotifications && data.allDriverNotifications.edges && data.allDriverNotifications.edges.length > 0) {
                setAllDriverNotifications(data.allDriverNotifications.edges)
                setUser({... user, isLoading: false})
                // console.log('user',user.driverId)
            }
            else
            {
            console.log('here in else');
            setUser({... user, isLoading: false})
            }
        }
    }) 

useFocusEffect(
      React.useCallback(() => {
        console.log('Refetching');
        refetch();
      }, [])
    );
```

Then I am using useFocusEffect, which is displaying my message on navigating but does not re fetch.

Comment: Can you please give us more information about your navigation package version?

Comment: It is @react-navigation/stack": ^5.12.8